# Cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:5004]

Tags: linux, configuration, port, haproxy

I need to start an haproxy server and I ran into a problem. It shows me this line:

> [ALERT] 251/140351 (749) : Starting frontend localnodes: cannot bind
>   socket [0.0.0.0:5004].

I tried other ports like 9000 and 80, but the same problem remains.
So the first question is why is it happening and what can I do to solve it?

Second question is, as a part of the haproxy start line is "`-p /run/haproxy.pid`". What is this file?

Will appreciate the quick response. Thanks in advance :)

My haproxy.conf:

```
global
   log /dev/log     local0
   log 127.0.0.1    local1 notice
   maxconn          256
   user             nobody
   group            haproxy
   daemon

defaults
   log              global
   mode             http
   option           httplog
   option           httplognull
   retries          3
   option           redispatch
   maxconn          2000
   timeout connect  5000
   timeout client   50000
   timeout server   50000

 frontend localnodes
   bind             *:5004
   mode             http
   default_backend  nodes
   option           forwardfor

backend nodes
   mode             http
   balance          roundrobin 
   server backend1 101.16.170.180:5004 check
```

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: RedHat7 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Check if selinux is enabled. If it is, that may be the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793885/haproxy-cannot-bind-socket-0-0-0-08888

Comment: I ran the command line and it solved the problem but it still says no route to host. Can you maybe give me further explanation on the uses of frontend and backend?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a clue about haproxy. Sounds like you should post this as a new question, since it is now a different problem than before.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. If the guy below won't be able to help me, I'll do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind the haproxy on port 80 without a root user.

Post the command below:

```
sudo netstat -antp |egrep "5004|9000"
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Nothing comes up. Forgot to say that I'm running on the root user.

Comment: I'm using "bind *:5004" on the frontend and "101.16.170.180:5004" on the backend if that helps

Comment: frontend and backend is on same server?

Comment: Yes in the same conf file. Now that I think about it it would be reasonable to put the backend on the other server but I just "learned" haproxy so I'm not familiar with the works. Can you maybe further explain the usage of front and back ends?

Comment: You _**can't**_ bind a process with a same port on same server.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. Can I upload the file here and can you tell me what did I do wrong?

Comment: Yes, update your question with config

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are giving both HAProxy and your application server the same port you want them to listen. Only one process can use a port at a time.

So, you need to decide which port you want to listen to with HAProxy, and which port you want to use with your application server.

The standard listening port for http protocol is 80, so in your `frontend localnodes` section you should use `bind *:80`. This requires you to start the daemon as root.

I recommend that you study the basics of TCP/IP and what it means when a service binds to a TCP port for listening incoming connections.

Comment: I understand but even after changing it  and trying different ports it still show the same error. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You need to check with `netstat -lnp` to see which programs are using the port you have specified and stop them.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I already killed it. It's the tcp proccess listening to 0.0.0.0:80. Even after that the problem still persists.

Comment: What is the exact configuration you are using that still fails? Please update it to the question.